# Can I pass reactor Context into grpc clientInterceptor implicitly?

Tags: java, grpc, project-reactor, grpc-java

Here's what I want to do at a high-level

1. Capture some http headers in a WebFilter
2. In the Controller method, I make a grpc call
3. I'd like to propagate the http headers as grpc Metadata headers

Currently, my working implementation is

1. WebFilter captures http headers and writes to reactor Context
2. Controller method extracts reactor Context and passes it into a Grpc ClientInterceptor
3. Grpc ClientInterceptor extracts http headers from Context and injects into Grpc Metadata headers

But I'd like to avoid having the Controller method doing any work (step 2 above).

Here's an implementation but looking for a way to get the http headers to Grpc Metadata without explicitly passing them in from Controller method.

**WebFilter**

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  return chain.filter(exchange)
    .contextWrite(Context.of("my-header", "header-value"));
}
```

**Controller method**

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> testHeaderPropagation() throws Exception {
  return Mono.deferContextual(reactorContext -> {
    Response response = grpcStub
      .withInterceptors(new GrpcClientInterceptor(reactorContext))
      .call(request);
    return Mono.just(response.getMessage());
  });
}
```

**GrpcClientInterceptor**

```
public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
  final ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);
  return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
    @Override
    public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
      Metadata.Key < String > key =
          Metadata.Key.of("filter-context", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
      headers.put(key, context.get("filter-context"));

      delegate().start(responseListener, headers);
    }
  };
}
```

I'd like simplify my Controller method  (remove the explicit passing in of the reactor Context into a clientInterceptor)

```
grpcStub.call(request)
```

I believe Spring Sleuth has a way of doing this but not sure how to adapt its approach.
What clever thing am I missing?

**Edit**

The reason I'm pushing for a version that involves minimal controller method code is because other developers will be writing the controller and methods. I want to establish a pattern that doesn't require extra wiring if possible, otherwise there's a chance someone forgets to do it or does it wrong.

**Edit**

Follow-up question. Instead of having the controller method pass in the Context to the clientInterceptor, I tried to get the Context inside the Grpc ClientInterceptor but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's is what I tried to do

```
public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
  final ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);

  return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
    @Override
    public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {

      Mono.deferContextual(context -> {
        Metadata.Key < String > key =
            Metadata.Key.of("CONTEXT-HEADER", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
        headers.put(key, context.get("CONTEXT-HEADER"));

        delegate().start(responseListener, headers);

        return Mono.empty();
      }).subscribe();


    }
  };
}
```

But I get an error

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context does not contain key CONTEXT-HEADER

Trying to understand why the reactor pipeline breaks here

Comment: yes, your second attempt cannot work because the `Context` is initialized at subscription time. here when calling `subscribe` you provide no Context, so it is empty.

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501349/using-hooks-and-a-lift-to-push-context-into-threadlocal).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another solution that doesn't require a WebFilter or reactor Context. But I'd still prefer some way to do "across-the-board automatic propagation".

In this solution I simply pass the ServerWebExchange injected into the controller method into a client interceptor, which will read the headers.

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<String> testHeaderPropagation(ServerWebExchange exchange) throws Exception {
  MyGrpcStub grpcStubWithInterceptor = attachMetadata(grpcStub, exchange);
  Response response = grpcStub
    .call(request);
  return Mono.just(response.getMessage());
}

public static <S extends AbstractStub<S>> S attachMetadata(S stub, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
  return stub.withInterceptors(new GrpcClientInterceptor(exchange));
}
```

Then my new GrpcClientInterceptor

```
public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();

  final ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);
  return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
    @Override
    public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
      Metadata.Key < String > key =
          Metadata.Key.of("my-header", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
      headers.put(key, httpHeaders.getFirst("my-header"));

      delegate().start(responseListener, headers);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

grpc and Reactor don't know about each other, so *someone* has to translate the contextual information between the two. Your current approach is the recommended one, even considering Sleuth (because across-the-board automatic propagation of `Context` is a mixed bag with big performance impact). This is pinpointing to your exact need, foolproof, so I'd keep it.

Comment: For argument's sake, how would you create an "across-the-board automatic propagation of Context"? Could you provide some code so I can evaluate?
ps-I found your blog . Very nice! Maybe you could create a blog entry about this (and on why it's bad)

Comment: I'm not sure it is even possible. The translation from grpc to reactor happens in the controller, so there's nothing much you can do other that provide your devs with helpers. also, I suspect there might be something horribly wrong with your code: is `grpcStub.call` blocking?

Comment: This [blog](https://bsideup.github.io/posts/daily_reactive/thread_locals/) seems like it could be key to solving such a problem

Comment: I am here looking for the solution for the same problem. I am counting on ThreadLocalContextLifter solution as mention here [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501349/using-hooks-and-a-lift-to-push-context-into-threadlocal). Thank you @kane